# How can I play Excitebots on a UK Wii?

Tags: nintendo-wii, region-lock, excitebots-trick-racing

Did Excitebots ever come out in the UK, and if so where can I buy it?

If not, what do I need to do (jailbreaking/modding/etc...) to get my Wii to play a US copy?

Comment: [No European release plans it looks like](http://wii.nintendolife.com/news/2009/05/nintendo_has_no_european_excitebots_plans)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ExciteBots), Excitebots only came out in the US.

If you do wish to play it however, I recommend you get a US copy from a store that ships to the UK (I use [VideoGamesPlus](http://www.videogamesplus.ca/) to get my US games) and soft-mod your Wii to play games from all regions (you can also get a US Wii, but that'll be quite expensive effort for just one game).

Soft-modding your Wii isn't a very straightforward process and can *potentially* damage your Wii. There are several guides on the internet for doing so, I used the one [here](http://gbatemp.net/topic/171901-modify-any-wii-43-below/) but I'm certain there are many other guides online.